# XHR2 addEventListener vs property

Tags: javascript, html

```
var _xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();

_xhr2.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e){ //#1
   console.log('progress');       
}, false);

_xhr2.upload.onprogress = function(e){ //#2
    console.log('progress'); 
};

_xhr2.open('POST', '/fileupload');
_xhr2.send(formData);
```

Could someone explain the difference between `#1` and `#2` above. Which one is preferred over the other? Because both seems to work.

The reason that I'm asking is because I'm playing around a bit with the HTML5 filereader + XHR2 upload, and in the MDN examples instances of `FileReader()` uses `#2`, while `XMLHttpRequest()` uses `#1`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [addEventListener vs onclick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, declaring `onprogress` property will overwrite the previous handlers bound to it, that's obvious and that's not the issue in you case because you're bounding it only to the new object instance.

I think **the only difference** is IE compatibility. `addEventListener` is supported for IE9+ while `onprogress` property (as well as other `on...` properties) is supported for IE5.5+.

*Note*:
Older versions of IE than 9 use `attachEvent` instead of `addEventListener`.

Comment: XHR2 and FileReader is only supported in IE10 anyway. I should have elaborated a bit, because what I'm curious is about if there is any performance difference and if there is any reason to unbind the event  listener if I go for #1. Got any info on that?

Comment: @Johan, I have no knowledge about which one has a better performance nor is it worth unbinding the event after its job is done. Personally, I __guess__ there's no difference in performance. I can't help you any further, though all I can do is (strongly) recommend you the answer marked as the possible duplicate. Never seen such highly developed answer. I hope it will help you.